# how do I loop over rows in an sqlite db from bash?

Tags: bash, sqlite

```
#!/bin/sh

rows=$(sqlite3 db 'select * from subscriptions;')

for row in $rows; do
  // curl $row['email']
done
```

I have a db that has email and keyword i want to make some curl requests for each row in the db.

Answer (score 2):

If the output is delimited by newlines, you could do

```
while IFS= read -r row; do
    echo "${row}"
done < <(sqlite3 db 'select * from subscriptions;')
```

Or you could read the rows into an array first, and iterate over it

```
mapfile -t rows < <(sqlite3 db 'select * from subscriptions;')
for row in "${rows}"; do
    echo "${row}";
done
```